# Convergence of a sequence in a nested local base

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence

I am following a proof of the proposition:

Let $B_{q} = \{B_{1},B_{2},...\} $ be a nested local base at $q \in X$ (X is a topological space) and let  be a sequence such that $c_{1} \in B_{1}, c_{2} \in B_{2},...$. Prove that <$c_{n}$> converges to $q$.

Proof: Let $H$ be an open set containing $q$. Because $B_{q}$ is a local base at $q$, there exists an $m \in N$ (N = Natural numbers) such that $B_{m} \subset H$. Since $B_{q}$ is nested, so $n > m$ impies $a_{n} \in B_{m} \subset H$, and so $c_{n} \to q$

I did not understand the last sentence. Why $c_{n} \to q$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last sentence should read "Since $B_q$ is nested, so $n>m$ implies $c_n\in B_m\subset H$, and so $c_n\to q$." This is simply the definition of convergence: $c_n\to q$ if for every open set $H$ containing $q$ there's $m$ such that for every $n>m, c_n\in H$.